# Check for dual/twin installed apps

Tags: android

I need to check if a clone of my app is installed on an Android device.
It is a big security concern for my ongoing project.

### Update:

I've now realised that clones are not *installed* but are actually able to run as a seperate instance without disturbing the original one.

Example of an app cloner:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl

How am I supposed to check at runtime that the running app has only one instance?

Comment: What do you mean by a "clone"? Are you concerned about an app that is already installed with the same `applicationId`? Or are you concerned about an app that is already installed with a different `applicationId` but the same features?

Comment: please see updated question body. Clones are somehow able to run without installation

Answer (score 0):

Android utilizes unique package strings to identify applications. Your application has a unique package string associated with it just like all Android apps.

To check if an app is installed on the device, you use the [Package Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager) and check with this code:

```
public static boolean doesUserHaveFacebookAppInstalled(Context context, 
                                                       String packageString){
    try{
        context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageString, 0 );
        return true;
    } catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){
        return false;
    }
}
```

So if you wanted to check if, for example, Facebook is installed, you would pass in their package string of `com.facebook.katana`. If it returns true, it is installed, if it is false, it is not installed.

In your situation, only one package is allowed on a device at a time, but the package String can be altered when creating a build. IE, your app package String could be `com.myapp.somename` and a debug version could be `com.myapp.somename-debug`. Both would be allowed to be installed as they are unique package Strings.

If you want to check what apps are installed on the device, you can use this code and it will get all installed applications that can be launched / opened:

```
public static List<ResolveInfo> getAllInstalledApps(Context context){
    try {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
        for(ResolveInfo r : pkgAppsList){
            if(r != null) {
                //You can use this String here to identify it while looping.
                String packageString = r.toString();
            }
        }
        return pkgAppsList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Use the results of the second code snippet to identify what apps are installed and check against the package string variations for your app to determine if other ones are installed.

Comment: I tried it, this code doesn't detect dual apps. Some phones allow users to duplicate an application which is useful for dual sim scenario, for example having two different whatsapp applications for each phone number.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic solution for this problem; some dual apps hook the system API, some run the app with different userId, and some clone the apk to a single mini VM to run.

The best approach, in my opinion, is to make your app can log-in at one place only when you open the app, connect to your server and your server forces to offline the previously logged-in device.

In that case, you may need a long connection or publish-subscribe-based messaging framework in your project (e.g., MQTT)